# Django channel web socket to console.log() to the Browser

Tags: javascript, django, django-channels

I am using npm wscat package to to send the message to django channels, when the
message is sent through the terminal, it prints on the server console as expected, how ever when I send it
to the browser the console is not logging the message

following is my working code:

#consumer.py

```
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer

class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        pass
    
    def receive(self, text_data):
        message_content = text_data
        print(message_content)
        self.send(text_data=message_content)
```

#routing.py

```
from django.urls import re_path

from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'ws/chat/$', consumers.ChatConsumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

#index.html

```
...
<script>

 let chat = null;

 function connect() {
  chat = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000/ws/chat/")

  chat.onopen = function (e) {
   console.log("Successfully connected to the WebSocket.");
  }

  chat.onmessage = function (result) {
   console.log(result.data);
   }

  chat.onerror = function (err) {
   console.log("WebSocket encountered an error: " + err.message);
   console.log("Closing the socket.");
  }
  chat.onclose = function (event) {
   console.log('WebSocket connection closed.');
  };
  <!--  -->
 }

 connect();
</script>
...
```

In the brower `chat.onopen` function works perfectly, and is diplayed in the browser,
however for some reason `chat.onmessage` function never gets executed.